# How to get a result from fragment using Navigation Architecture Component?

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-jetpack, android-architecture-navigation

Let's say that we have two fragments: `MainFragment` and `SelectionFragment`. The second one is build for selecting some object, e.g. an integer. There are different approaches in receiving result from this second fragment like callbacks, buses etc.

Now, if we decide to use Navigation Architecture Component in order to navigate to second fragment we can use this code:

```
NavHostFragment.findNavController(this).navigate(R.id.action_selection, bundle)
```

where `bundle` is an instance of `Bundle` (of course). As you can see there is no access to `SelectionFragment` where we could put a callback. The question is, how to receive a result with Navigation Architecture Component?

Comment: Have `SelectionFragment` update a shared `ViewModel` (directly or indirectly), where `MainFragment` is subscribed to find out about changes in that `ViewModel`.

Comment: Provided that you're using `ViewModel`, which is not related to Navigation Component.

Comment: Correct. They are designed to work together, and [Google is indicating that a shared `ViewModel` is the recommended way to communicate between fragments when using the Navigation library](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50752558/115145).

Comment: I think you should post it as answer.

Comment: Use graph scoped shared view models https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55137338/android-navigation-component-with-shared-view-models

Comment: use `fragmentManager.putFragment(bundle, TargetFragment.EXTRA_CALLER, this)` before navigating, then in the target fragment find the called fragment `fragmentManager?.getFragment(args, EXTRA_CALLER)`

Comment: use this way https://stackoverflow.com/a/69005732/4797289

Answer (score 113):

They have added a [fix for this](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/79672220#comment55) in the 2.3.0-alpha02 release.

If navigating from **Fragment A** to **Fragment B** and **A** needs a result from **B**:

```
findNavController().currentBackStackEntry?.savedStateHandle?.getLiveData<Type>("key")?.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {result ->
    // Do something with the result.
}
```

If on **Fragment B** and need to set the result:

```
findNavController().previousBackStackEntry?.savedStateHandle?.set("key", result)
```

I ended up creating two extensions for this:

```
fun Fragment.getNavigationResult(key: String = "result") =
    findNavController().currentBackStackEntry?.savedStateHandle?.getLiveData<String>(key)

fun Fragment.setNavigationResult(result: String, key: String = "result") {
    findNavController().previousBackStackEntry?.savedStateHandle?.set(key, result)
}
```

Comment: This should be accepted as the correct answer.so simple and do the work perfectly

Comment: and maybe it will be useful for someone with Navigation Component and dialogs https://stackoverflow.com/a/62054347/7968334

Comment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't put value with type class com.experienceapi.auth.models.LogonModel into saved state . Any idea?

Comment: Make sure to implement the Parcelable interface in order to save custom objects.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.Implemented it but still the same result.Should I write findNavController().previousBackStackEntry?.savedStateHandle?.set("key", result) in the writeParcel() method? Please reply.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62343552/livedata-not-able-to-observe-the-changes

Comment: It is very simple and useful.

Comment: it's 2.3.0-alpha02 version? or 1.3.0-alpha02

Comment: From documentation: The value must have a type that could be stored in android.os.Bundle

Comment: Beware `currentBackStackEntry` will not work correctly with `<dialog>` destinations (see [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-programmatic#additional_considerations)), you need to use `getBackStackEntry()` with the ID of your destination then

Comment: It has a problem. If you navigate from Fragment B to Fragment A. Fragment A obtains the data from live data, which is fine. But if you restart the fragment (configuration change), then observer works again, because live data has data cached.

Comment: @Andrew just remove the observer after data was consumed.

Comment: any solution for live data caching the value, the issue is After moving from fragment B to A with a value, I am moving to Fragment C from A and when I press back button fragment A has the same value in which I get from B

Comment: Using this logic, I am able navigate back to fragment A with the arguments, but after that it won't let me go back to fragment B. It says the navController.currentDestination = null.

Answer (score 105):

Since Fragment [KTX 1.3.6](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/fragment#1.3.6) Android supports passing data between fragments or between fragments and activities. It's similar to `startActivityForResult` logic.

Here is an example with Navigation Component. You can read more about it [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/pass-data-between)

**build.gradle**

```
implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.3.6"
```

**FragmentA.kt**

```
class FragmentA : Fragment() {

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        // Step 1. Listen for fragment results
        setFragmentResultListener(FragmentB.REQUEST_KEY) { key, bundle -> 
            // read from the bundle
        }

        // Step 2. Navigate to Fragment B
        findNavController().navigate(R.id.fragmentB)
    }
}
```

**FragmentB.kt**

```
class FragmentB : Fragment() {

    companion object {
        val REQUEST_KEY = "FragmentB_REQUEST_KEY"
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        buttonA.setOnClickListener { view -> 
            // Step 3. Set a result
            setFragmentResult(REQUEST_KEY, bundleOf("data" to "button clicked"))
            
            // Step 4. Go back to Fragment A
            findNavController().navigateUp()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This problem exists with your solution: https://stackoverflow.com/q/63669116/3248593

Comment: Very interesting and simple decision, it is was I need to return data from child fragment

Comment: @MortezaRastgoo I think that problem can be solved with viewmodel or any persisting data strategy

Comment: not working for me, Fragment A result listener never called and don't know why

Comment: not working here either.

Answer (score 43):

Use these extension functions

```
fun <T> Fragment.getNavigationResult(key: String = "result") =
    findNavController().currentBackStackEntry?.savedStateHandle?.get<T>(key)

fun <T> Fragment.getNavigationResultLiveData(key: String = "result") =
        findNavController().currentBackStackEntry?.savedStateHandle?.getLiveData<T>(key)

fun <T> Fragment.setNavigationResult(result: T, key: String = "result") {
    findNavController().previousBackStackEntry?.savedStateHandle?.set(key, result)
}
```

So if you want to send result from Fragment **B** to fragment **A**

Inside Fragment **B**

```
setNavigationResult(false, "someKey")
```

Inside Fragment **A**

```
val result = fragment.getNavigationResultLiveData<Boolean>("someKey")
result.observe(viewLifecycleOwner){ booleanValue-> doSomething(booleanValue)
```

Important note

> In the Fragment B you need to set the result (setNavigationResult())
> in the started or resumed state (before onStop() or onDestroy()),
> otherwise previousBackStackEntry will be already null.

Important note #2

> If you’d only like to handle a result only once, you must call
> remove() on the SavedStateHandle to clear the result. If you do not
> remove the result, the LiveData will continue to return the last
> result to any new Observer instances.

More information [in the official guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-programmatic#returning_a_result).

Comment: I tried using savedStateHandle and was able to set the key with result but I never received the update in my observer.. I am using version 2.3.4...

Comment: @shadygoneinsane I experienced the same issue. When I tried to debug it, I found that is very important in what lifecycle is `navController.previousBackStackEntry` called. For example in `onStop()` or `onDestroy()` is the `previousBackStackEntry` already `null`. So you need to set the result before. According to [this documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/NavController#getPreviousBackStackEntry()): `getPreviousBackStackEntry` - return the previous visible entry on the back stack or null if the back stack has less than two visible entries.

Comment: Notice that if. 
 "result.observe(viewLifecycleOwner){ booleanValue-> doSomething(booleanValue)}"   
does not resolve to boolean, place the function inside parenthesis like this: "observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { booleanValue -> })". 
Happy codingg

Comment: If its not working for you . Try replacing scope from viewLifecycleOwner with findNavController().currentBackStackEntry

Comment: this way has an issue if the user come back to first Fragmment again the live data called twice or more, use this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/69005732/4797289

Comment: @Tomas thanks. I faced lifecycle issue too and by changing the owner of observer result start showing just fine.

Answer (score 30):

According to Google: [you should try to use shared ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#sharing). Check below example from Google:

**Shared ViewModel** that will contain shared data and can be accessed from different fragments.

```
public class SharedViewModel extends ViewModel {
    private final MutableLiveData<Item> selected = new MutableLiveData<Item>();

    public void select(Item item) {
        selected.setValue(item);
    }

    public LiveData<Item> getSelected() {
        return selected;
    }
}
```

MasterFragment that updates ViewModel:

```
public class MasterFragment extends Fragment {

    private SharedViewModel model;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        model = ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity()).get(SharedViewModel.class);
        itemSelector.setOnClickListener(item -> {
            model.select(item);
        });
    }
}
```

DetailsFragment that uses shared ViewModel:

```
public class DetailFragment extends Fragment {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SharedViewModel model = ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity()).get(SharedViewModel.class);
        model.getSelected().observe(this, item -> {
           // Update the UI.
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem with this is you are scoping your viewmodel to the activity with `getActivity()`. This means it will never be cleared (uses extra memory and could cause unexpected results when you navigate back to these fragments later, and stale data is shown). You should use `ViewModelProviders.of(parent)...` instead.

Comment: what if we don't have view model ?

Comment: @CarsonHolzheimer what is parent here?

Comment: @CarsonHolzheimer the problem you saying solved here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55137338/android-navigation-component-with-shared-view-models

Comment: I wouldn't say solved. They are some less than ideal workarounds. Shared viewmodels in general aren't always a good idea. For simply returning a result to a previous activity they hard to read and more difficult to build on than the upcoming API for returning with a result.

Comment: "the upcoming API for returning with a result." Does this API now exist? If so, got a link? @CarsonHolzheimer

Comment: Sorry it still doesn't exist. It's been a long time coming. Search for startactivityforresult analog on Google issue tracker

Comment: What if I don't want to consider using this approach?

Comment: you should use   private val model: SharedViewModel by activityViewModels()

Answer (score 6):

with a little improvement of @LeHaine 's answer, you can use these methods for navigation `2.3.0-alpha02` and above

```
fun <T> Fragment.getNavigationResult(key: String) =
    findNavController().currentBackStackEntry?.savedStateHandle?.getLiveData<T>(key)

fun <T> Fragment.setNavigationResult(result: T, key: String) {
    findNavController().previousBackStackEntry?.savedStateHandle?.set(key, result)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I created a wrapper function that's similar to LeHaine's answer, but it handles more cases.

To pass a result to a parent from a child:

```
findNavController().finishWithResult(PickIntervalResult.WEEKLY)
```

To get result from a child in a parent:

```
findNavController().handleResult<PickIntervalResult>(
    viewLifecycleOwner,
    R.id.navigation_notifications, // current destination
    R.id.pickNotificationIntervalFragment // child destination
    ) { result ->
        binding.textNotifications.text = result.toString()
}
```

My wrapper isn't so simple as LeHaine's one, but it is generic and handles cases as:

1. A few children for one parent
2. Result is any class that implements `Parcelable`
3. Dialog destination

See the implementation on the [github](https://github.com/VysotskiVadim/jetpack-navigation-example/blob/master/app/src/main/java/dev/vadzimv/jetpack/navigation/example/navigation/Result.kt) or check out [an article that explains how it works](https://vadzimv.dev/2021/07/24/jetpack-navigation-result-to-parent.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
fun <Type> BaseNavigationActivity<*,*,*>.getNavigationResult(key : String, @IdRes viewId: Int)  =
    this.findNavController(viewId).currentBackStackEntry?.savedStateHandle?.getLiveData<Type>(key)


fun <Type> BaseNavigationActivity<*,*,*>.setNavigationResult(result: Type, key: String, @IdRes viewId: Int){
   this.findNavController(viewId).previousBackStackEntry?.savedStateHandle?.set<Type>(key, result)
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code is a lot more helpful when it is accompanied by an explanation. 
Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please edit your answer and explain 
how it answers the specific question being asked. See [How to Answer]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer)

Answer (score -3):

I would suggest you to use [NavigationResult](https://github.com/PHELAT/NavigationResult) library which is an add-on for JetPack's Navigation Component and lets you to `navigateUp` with Bundle.
I've also wrote a [blog post](https://android.jlelse.eu/navigateup-with-bundle-c595ff6d91ba) about this on Medium.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this library as it highly relies on inheritance. Sooner or later this will limit you in your endeavour.

TL;DR Favor composition of inheritance: 
https://medium.com/@rufuszh90/effective-java-item-16-favour-composition-over-inheritance-ed82e482fd1a

Answer (score -3):

Just an alternative to the other answers...

EventBus with MutableShareFlow as it core in a shared object (ex: repo) and an observer describe in [here](https://proandroiddev.com/android-singleliveevent-redux-with-kotlin-flow-b755c70bb055)

Looks like things are moving away from LiveData and going in Flow direction.

Worth to have a look.