# Navigate to a particular fragment when app launched from sharesheet

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-navigation

I am using Jetpack Navigation in my app having a single activity and two fragments (Fragment A which is also the home fragment and Fragment B which can be navigated from Fragment A).

There is an `intent-filter` added to the `MainActivity` as shown below which can accept plain text.

```
 <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <data android:mimeType="@string/text_mime_type_text_plain"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

When a user selects my app from the Android sharesheet, the end goal is to pass the data received from the Intent to the Fragment B. Currently, I am receiving the Intent in Fragment A (Home Fragment) and then using `NavController` to navigate to Fragment B using the below code.

```
  private fun checkReceivedIntent() {
    val receivedUrlIntent = activity?.intent
    val intentAction = receivedUrlIntent?.action
    val intentType = receivedUrlIntent?.type

    if (intentAction == Intent.ACTION_SEND && intentType != null) {
        if (intentType == getString(R.string.text_mime_type_text_plain) ) {
            val receivedText = receivedUrlIntent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT)
            val action = FragmentADirections.actionFragmentAToFragmentB(receivedText)
            findNavController().navigate(action)
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that when Fragment B is opened, on pressing the back button or back arrow of Toolbar (Even when pressed multiple times) the Fragment A doesn't appear and Fragment B keeps on reappearing.

I don't know what I am missing. Is this a proper way to open a particular fragment when the app is opened by the user from the share sheet inside another app?

**Edit**

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:animateLayoutChanges="true">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/navHostFragment"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:defaultNavHost="true"
    app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />

<com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
    android:id="@+id/bottomAppBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    app:fabCradleMargin="8dp"

    />

<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fabMainActivity"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_add"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/bottomAppBar" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Can you please share how you define the container in your MainActivity xml ?
Also I'm wondering where you call `checkReceivedIntent` ? I'm assuming that it's inside Fragment A ?

Comment: @IbrahimAli I have updated the question. Yes, I am calling checkReceivedIntent in the Fragment A.

Comment: In your `<action` in `nav_graph.xml` do you use any `popUp` or something while opening the fragment B?

Comment: @IbrahimAli Nope.

Comment: `checkReceivedIntent()` will be called everytime when you try to load Fragment A, hence it keeps navigating to B even when you press back

Comment: @MehulKanzariya Could you please clarify. So you are trying to return to `Fragment A` from `Fragment B`? And you cannot to do that, because of navigation from  sharesheet. Right?

Comment: @JavaGhost Yes, you are correct. So, is there any other preferred way to do this?

Comment: after receiving the values from intents, clear it! since it remains available when you navigate back to fragment A, it again fetches values and proceeds forward...

Answer (score 4):

Why you cannot directly go to `Fragment` B once received the the `Intent` Extra in your `Activity`. Just **instead** of defining `Fragment` in the xml, or as a `startDestination` you could simply perform switch to `Fragment` B

In the `Activity`:

```
       Navigation
            .findNavController(binding.root)
            .navigate(
                R.id.navigation_from_intent_actions, bundle,
                NavOptions.Builder()
                    .setIntentExtra(extras)
                    .build()
            )
```

**UPDATE**

To return to previous fragment, you can easily do with getting `Fragment` from the `FragmentManager` (it won't be killed, because it's your home `Fragment`). You can do it in the next way:

```
  private fun returnWithName() {
      val name = name_input.text.toString()

      (targetFragment as? FragmentA)?.setName(name)
      activity?.supportFragmentManager?
           .popBackStackImmediate()
  }
```

And later just check updated result from `FragmentB`. To which `Fragment` you need to navigate.

**Note.** There is also another way to share data with Shared `ViewModel`. However, you would need to transfer result from `ViewModel` back to `FragmentA`. And then check for new transaction parameters. It's [also described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50891606/4133301).

Comment: Since Fragment A is already set as the home destination, would it be a good approach to skip it and directly navigate to Fragment B?

Comment: @MehulKanzariya Yeah, it's kind of another thing. Please check the updated answer.