# LiveData not able to observe the changes

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-databinding, android-livedata

I am updating a **LiveData value from a DialogFragment in the ViewModel**, but not able to get the value in Fragment.

**The ViewModel:**

```
class OtpViewModel(private val otpUseCase: OtpUseCase, analyticsModel: IAnalyticsModel) : BaseViewModel(analyticsModel) {
    override val globalNavModel = GlobalNavModel(titleId = R.string.otp_contact_title, hasGlobalNavBar = false)

    private val _contactListLiveData = MutableLiveData<List<Contact>>()
    val contactListLiveData: LiveData<List<Contact>>
        get() = _contactListLiveData

    private lateinit var cachedContactList: LiveData<List<Contact>>
    private val contactListObserver = Observer<List<Contact>> {
        _contactListLiveData.value = it
    }



    private lateinit var cachedResendOtpResponse: LiveData<LogonModel>
    private val resendOTPResponseObserver = Observer<LogonModel> {
        _resendOTPResponse.value = it
    }

    private var _resendOTPResponse = MutableLiveData<LogonModel>()
    val resendOTPResponseLiveData: LiveData<LogonModel>
        get() = _resendOTPResponse

    var userSelectedIndex : Int = 0 //First otp contact selected by default

    val selectedContact : LiveData<Contact>
        get() = MutableLiveData(contactListLiveData.value?.get(userSelectedIndex))

    override fun onCleared() {
        if (::cachedContactList.isInitialized) {
            cachedContactList.removeObserver(contactListObserver)
        }

        if (::cachedOtpResponse.isInitialized) {
            cachedOtpResponse.removeObserver(otpResponseObserver)
        }

        super.onCleared()
    }

    fun updateIndex(pos: Int){
        userSelectedIndex = pos
    }

    fun onChangeDeliveryMethod() {
        navigate(
            OtpVerificationHelpCodeSentBottomSheetFragmentDirections
                .actionOtpContactVerificationBottomSheetToOtpChooseContactFragment()
        )
    }

    fun onClickContactCancel() {
        navigateBackTo(R.id.logonFragment, true)
    }

    fun retrieveContactList() {
        cachedContactList = otpUseCase.fetchContactList()
        cachedContactList.observeForever(contactListObserver)
    }



    fun resendOTP(contactId : String){
        navigateBack()
        cachedResendOtpResponse = otpUseCase.resendOTP(contactId)
        cachedResendOtpResponse.observeForever(resendOTPResponseObserver)

    }
}
```

**The BaseViewModel:**

```
abstract class BaseViewModel(val analyticsModel: IAnalyticsModel) : ViewModel() {
    protected val _navigationCommands: SingleLiveEvent<NavigationCommand> = SingleLiveEvent()
    val navigationCommands: LiveData<NavigationCommand> = _navigationCommands

    abstract val globalNavModel: GlobalNavModel


    /**
     * Posts a navigation event to the navigationsCommands LiveData observable for retrieval by the view
     */
    fun navigate(directions: NavDirections) {
        _navigationCommands.postValue(NavigationCommand.ToDirections(directions))
    }

    fun navigate(destinationId: Int) {
        _navigationCommands.postValue(NavigationCommand.ToDestinationId(destinationId))
    }

    fun navigateBack() {
        _navigationCommands.postValue(NavigationCommand.Back)
    }

    fun navigateBackTo(destinationId: Int, isInclusive: Boolean) {
        _navigationCommands.postValue(NavigationCommand.BackTo(destinationId, isInclusive))
    }

    open fun init() {
        // DEFAULT IMPLEMENTATION - override to initialize your view model
    }


    /**
     * Called from base fragment when the view has been created.
     */
    fun onViewCreated() {
        analyticsModel.onNewState(getAnalyticsPathCrumb())
    }

    /**
     * gets the Path for the current page to be used for the trackstate call
     *
     * Override this method if you need to modify the path
     *
     * the page id for the track state call will be calculated in the following manner
     * 1) analyticsPageId
     * 2) titleId
     * 3) the page title string
     */
    protected fun getAnalyticsPathCrumb() : AnalyticsBreadCrumb {

        return analyticsBreadCrumb {
            pathElements {
                if (globalNavModel.analyticsPageId != null) {
                    waPath {
                        path = PathElement(globalNavModel.analyticsPageId as Int)
                    }
                } else if (globalNavModel.titleId != null) {
                    waPath {
                        path = PathElement(globalNavModel.titleId as Int)
                    }
                } else {
                    waPath {
                        path = PathElement(globalNavModel.title ?: "")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**The DialogFragment:**

```kotlin
class OtpVerificationHelpCodeSentBottomSheetFragment : BaseBottomSheetDialogFragment(){

    private lateinit var rootView: View
    lateinit var binding: BottomSheetFragmentOtpVerificationHelpCodeSentBinding

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

        viewModel = getViewModel<OtpViewModel>()

        binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.bottom_sheet_fragment_otp_verification_help_code_sent, container, false)

        rootView = binding.root

        return rootView
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)


        val otpViewModel = (viewModel as OtpViewModel)
        binding.viewmodel = otpViewModel

        otpViewModel.resendOTPResponseLiveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {

            it?.let { resendOtpResponse ->
                if(resendOtpResponse.statusCode.equals("000")){
                    //valid status code
                    requireActivity().toastMessageOtp(getString(R.string.otp_code_verification_sent))
                }else{
                    //show the error model
                    //it?.errorModel?.let { it1 -> handleDiasNetworkError(it1) }
                }
            }

        })
    }
}
```

I am calling the **resendOTP(contactId : String)** method of the viewmodel from the xml file of the **DialogFragment**:

```
 <TextView
            android:id="@+id/verification_help_code_sent_resend_code"
            style="@style/TruTextView.SubText2.BottomActions"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/spaceXl"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="@string/verification_help_resend_code"
            android:onClick="@{() -> viewmodel.resendOTP(Integer.toString(viewmodel.userSelectedIndex))}"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/top_guideline" />
```

**Now whenever I try to call resendOTPResponseLiveData from the Fragment  it does not gets called:**

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        Log.d("OtpVerify" , "OnViewCreatedCalled")
        viewModel.onViewCreated()
        val otpViewModel = (viewModel as OtpViewModel)

        binding.lifecycleOwner = this
        binding.viewmodel = otpViewModel
        binding.toAuthenticated = OtpVerifyFragmentDirections.actionOtpVerifyFragmentToAuthenticatedActivity()
        binding.toVerificationBtmSheet = OtpVerifyFragmentDirections.actionOtpVerifyFragmentToOtpContactVerificationCodeSentBottomSheet()


        otpViewModel.resendOTPResponseLiveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            if(it?.statusCode.equals("000")){
                //valid status code
                requireActivity().toastMessageOtp(getString(R.string.otp_code_verification_sent))
            }else{
                //show the error model
                it?.errorModel?.let { it1 -> handleDiasNetworkError(it1) }
            }
        })

    }
```

So what wrong I am doing here.

**EDIT**

Basically I need clicklistener(resend button click) in dialogfragment, and need to read it in the fragment. So I used the concept of SharedViewModel.

So I make necessary changes in the ViewModel:

```
private val selected = MutableLiveData<LogonModel>()

 fun select(logonModel: LogonModel) {
        selected.value = logonModel
    }

    fun getSelected(): LiveData<LogonModel> {
        return selected
    }
```

**In the DialogFragment:**

```
 otpViewModel.resendOTPResponseLiveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer{

           otpViewModel.select(it);

        })
```

And in the fragment where I want to read the value:

```
otpViewModel.getSelected().observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {

            Log.d("OtpVerify" , "ResendCalled")
            // Update the UI.
            if(it?.statusCode.equals("000")){
                //valid status code
                requireActivity().toastMessageOtp(getString(R.string.otp_code_verification_sent))
            }else{
                //show the error model
                it?.errorModel?.let { it1 -> handleDiasNetworkError(it1) }
            }
        })
```

But it is still not working.

Edit:

ViewModel Source for fragment:

```
viewModel = getSharedViewModel<OtpViewModel>(from = {
            Navigation.findNavController(container as View).getViewModelStoreOwner(R.id.two_step_authentication_graph)
        })
```

ViewModel Source for dialogfragment:

```
viewModel = getViewModel<OtpViewModel>()
```

Comment: It's not clear from the code that a value ever will be set on `cachedResendOtpResponse`, since we don't know exactly what `OtpUseCase.resendOTP` does. I also don't understand what the purpose of `cachedResendOtpResponse` is. Seems to me like you could do the same thing with just a private `MutableLiveData` for the Contact ID string, and a public `Transformations.switchMap` which reacts on changes to that string and returns your `LiveData<LogonModel>`.

Comment: Hi Michael, OtpUseCase.resendOTP makes a network call and sends the data.the return type is of  LiveData<LogonModel>. So to capture the livedata , I have done it in that way , otherwise it will return a compilation error , expected livedata found mutablelivedata.

Comment: Any more details required @Michael?

Comment: My point is that we can't verify its correctness since we don't have that code, so for all we know you could have a bug there that's causing this problem.

Comment: Hi Michael, the livedata can observe values correctly from the dialogfragment , but fails for fragment.So , I assume there is no problem in OtpUseCase.resendOTP

Comment: Could you please share how you actually get the ViewModel instance from both the Fragment and the Dialog?

Comment: @Sarquella edited the question.please check

Comment: What's ```getViewModel```?

Answer (score 3):

Being new-ish to the Jetpack library and Kotlin a few months back I ran into a similar issue, if I understand you correctly.

I think the issue here is that you are retrieving you ViewModel using the `by viewModels` which means the ViewModel you get back will only be scoped to the current fragments context... If you would like to share a view model across multiple parts of your application they have to be activity scoped.

So for example:

```
//this will only work for the current fragment, using this declaration here and anywhere else and observing changes wont work, the observer will never fire, except if the method is called within the same fragment that this is declared
private val viewModel: AddPatientViewModel by viewModels {
    InjectorUtils.provideAddPatientViewModelFactory(requireContext())
}

//this will work for the ANY fragment in the current activies scope, using this code and observing anywhere else should work, the observer will fire, except if the method is called fro another activity
private val patientViewModel: PatientViewModel by activityViewModels {
    InjectorUtils.providePatientViewModelFactory(requireContext())
}
```

Notice my `viewModel` of type `AddPatientViewModel` is scoped to the current fragments context only via `viewModel: XXX by viewModels`, any changes etc made to that particular ViewModel will only be propagated in my current fragment.

Where as `patientViewModel` of type `PatientViewModel` is scoped to the activities context via `patientViewModel: XXX by activityViewModels`.
This means that as long as both fragments belong to the same activity, and you get the ViewModel via `... by activityViewModels` you should be able to observe any changes made to the ViewModel on a global scope (global meaning any fragment within the same activity where it was declared).

With all the above in mind if your viewModel is correctly scoped to your activity and in both fragments you retrieve the viewModel using the `by activityViewModels` and updating the value being observed via `XXX.postValue(YYY)` or `XXX.value = YYY` you should be able to observe any changes made to the ViewModel from anywhere within the same activity context.

Hope that makes sense, it's late here, and I saw this question just before I hit the sack!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are actually not sharing the *ViewModel* between the *Fragment* and the *Dialog*. To share instances of a *ViewModel* they must be retrieved from the same `ViewModelStore`.

The syntax you are using to retrieve the *ViewModels* seems to be from a third party framework. I feel like probably [Koin](https://insert-koin.io).

If that is the case, note that in *Koin*, `getViewModel` retrieves the *ViewModel* from the *Fragment*'s own *ViewModelStore*. So, you are retrieving the *ViewModel* in your *DialogFragment* from its own *ViewModelStore*. On the other hand, in your *Fragment*, you are retrieving it using `getSharedViewModel`, in which you can specify which *ViewModelStore* it should retrieve the *ViewModel* from. So you are retrieving the *ViewModel* from two different *ViewModelStores*, and so, getting two different *ViewModel*. Interacting with one of those does not affect the other, as they are not the same instance.

To solve it, you should retrieve the *ViewModel* in both your *Fragment* and *DialogFragment* from the same *ViewModelStore*. For example, you could use `getSharedViewModel` in both, maybe specifying the same *ViewModelStore* manually at each, or even, without even specifying, which *Koin* will default to their *Activity*'s one.

You could also even just use `getViewModel` in your *Fragment*, then pass its own specific *ViewModelStore* to the *DialogFragment*, in which you could then use `getSharedViewModel`, specifying the passed *Fragment*'s *ViewModelStore*.

Comment: I think I have already tried this.I will check it again and let you know.

Comment: Ok! Let me know. In case it still does not work, could you also share some of your OtpUseCase. I see you assign cachedResendOtpResponse to the result of a call to OtpUseCase, then observe it forever (stopping it in onCleared) and update resendOTPResponseLiveData it its callback. Also, if you could share how you declare the ViewModel in the Koin module would also be great.