# Navigation controller AlertDialog click listner

Tags: kotlin, android-alertdialog, android-architecture-navigation

I'm using Android's Navigation component and I'm wondering how to setup AlertDialog from a fragment with a click listener.

MyFragment

```
fun MyFragment : Fragment(), MyAlertDailog.MyAlertDialogListener {
     ...

    override fun onDialogPostiveCLick(dialog: DialogFragment) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Listener returns a postive click")
    }

     fun launchMyAlertDialog() {
          // Here I would typically call setTargetFragment() and then show the dialog. 
          // but findnavcontroller doesn't have setTargetFragment()
         findNavController.navigate(MyFragmentDirection.actionMyFragmentToMyAlertDialog())
     }
}
```

MyAlertDialog

```
class MyAlertDialog : DialogFragment() {

    ... 

    internal lateinit var listener: MyAlertDialogListener

    interface MyAlertDialogListener{
        fun onDialogPostiveCLick(dialog: DialogFragment)
    }

    override fun onCreateDialog(savdInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
        return activity?.let {
            val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(it) 
            builder.setMessage("My Dialog message")
                .setPositiveButton("Positive", DialogInterface.OnClickListener {
                    listener = targetFragment as MyAlertDialogListener                    
                    listener.onDialogPositiveClick(this)
                }
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

This currently receives a null point exception when initializing the listener in MyAlertDialog.

Comment: What is `targetFragment` in `targetFragment as MyAlertDialogListener` ?

Answer (score 0):

To use `targetFragment`, you have to set it first as you commented, unfortunately jetpack navigation does not do this for you (hence the null pointer exception). Check out this thread for alternative solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50752558/12321475

What I can offer you is an alternative. If the use-case is as simple as displaying a dialog above current fragment, then do:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog
...

class MyFragment : Fragment() {
     ...

    fun onDialogPostiveCLick() {
        Log.i(TAG, "Listener returns a postive click")
    }

     fun launchMyAlertDialog() {
          AlertDialog.Builder(activity)
            .setMessage("My Dialog message")
            .setPositiveButton("Positive") { _, _ -> onDialogPostiveCLick() }
            .setCancellable(false)
            .create().show()
     }
}
```